# nodejs dynamically increment JSON object property without getting undefined on the first try

Tags: node.js, json

I need to dynamically create and increment a property in a JSON object. My code needs to check for undefined on the first try, else it will error out if I try to simply increment a non-existing property.

The code works, but I'm itching for a way to simplify the code below?

```
let errorcount = {}
let code = "404" // eg. 404 response code - this is dynamic, so it can be any response code returned by API

// increment operation, to be called after getting response code from API
// can this be made simpler??
if (errorCount[`response ${code}`] === undefined) {
  errorCount[`response ${code}`] = 1
} else {
  errorCount[`response ${code}`]++
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(errorCount))
// errorcount = {"response 404" : 800 } // eg. result for 404 errors aggregated
```

Comment: You can do it like this to make it shorter, but the logic is basically the same. `errorCount['response ${code}'] = (errorCount[`response ${code}`] || 0) + 1;`

Comment: @Jackyef thanks for the reply! you should make this an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that it is slightly shorter.

```
const errorcount = {}
const code = "404" // eg. 404 response code - this is dynamic, so it can be any response code returned by API

// increment operation, to be called after getting response code from API
// can this be made simpler??
const responseString = `response ${code}`
errorCount[responseString ] = errorCount[responseString] ? errorCount[responseString]+1 : 1 ;

console.log(JSON.stringify(errorCount))
// errorcount = {"response 404" : 800 } // eg. result for 404 errors aggregated
```

You could also prepopulate the codes in a file.js. I would probably do it myself that way.
And then the end result would be:

```
const errorCount = { 400:0, 401:0, 402:0,... }
errorCount[code] +=1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(errorCount))
```

Comment: yes, I was doing it this way initially, then I thought there's too many response codes to declare upfront. Would be nice if it was dynamic. Maybe I'm missing out on a canonical way to declare dynamically, without checking for undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Writing this as an answer as the OP requested.

You can do it like this to make it shorter, but the logic is basically the same.

```
errorCount[`response ${code}`] = (errorCount[`response ${code}`] || 0) + 1;
```

The final code snippet looks like:

```
let errorcount = {}
let code = "404" // eg. 404 response code - this is dynamic, so it can be any response code returned by API

// increment operation, to be called after getting response code from API
// can this be made simpler??
errorCount[`response ${code}`] = (errorCount[`response ${code}`] || 0) + 1;

console.log(JSON.stringify(errorCount))
// errorcount = {"response 404" : 800 } // eg. result for 404 errors aggregated
```